What objects can be filmed for better engagement?
I've noticed when uploading a video to SpookTube, the people in the chat will point out things like "that's a creepy building", or "the dive bell looks fancy" (not exact quotes, but gets the point across).
They seem to say these things when you film certain objects, such as the old factory building you enter in the Old World, or the dive bell you take to reach the Old World.  With the point of the game to get as many views as possibly on the videos you make, filming certain content will boost your views.  Thus, what are the entities you can film to boost engagement?

The tag is the actual game name, right?

@pinckerman yes https://store.steampowered.com/app/2881650/Content_Warning/
